# GridView/RadGrid - Extract original typed object from datasource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, telerik

I am using a Telerik RadGrid control to display data pulled from a db.

The markup looks as follows:

```
<MasterTableView runat="server" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false" DataKeyNames="PersonNumber" AllowNaturalSort="false">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="RowSelectColumn"  HeaderText="&nbsp;" Resizable="false" Reorderable="false">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="18px" />
                </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" HtmlEncode="false">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="250px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="E-mail Address" UniqueName="EmailAddress"  DataField="EmailAddress" SortExpression="EmailAddress" HtmlEncode="false">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="200px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Invite Status" UniqueName="InviteResult" DataField="InviteResult" SortExpression="InviteResult">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>            
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
```

I have a class, say MyObject, which maps to a data row (some properties aren't shown in the grid). I need it so when a user selects a row(s), I am able to retrieve the original object that the row represents/is bound to. I know the key is to extract from the data source, but how do I map a row to it's equivalent data in the source?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataKeyNames to include values that are not present in your grid, by setting these when you retrieve a row either client or serverside you have access to additional columns, the most common uses are with the 2 functions SelectedIndexChanged (Server-Side) and OnRowSelected (client-side).  You could either store your extra columns in the datakeynames or use a primary key and some linq to retrieve the same row(s) from your datasource

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id,HiddenVal1,HiddenVal2" ClientDataKeyNames="Id,HiddenVal1,HiddenVal2,clientsideSpecialId">
    <Columns>
      <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Select" Text="Select" UniqueName="SelectColumn" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact name" DataField="ContactName" />
      <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ContactTitle" HeaderText="Contact title" DataField="ContactTitle" />
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
  <ClientSettings>
   <ClientEvents OnRowSelected="RowSelected"/>
  </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Retrieving those dataKeyName values server side on selected index changed:

```
protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadGrid1.SelectedItems == null || RadGrid1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;

    var dataItem = RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0] as GridDataItem;
    if (dataItem != null)
    {
        var myId = dataItem.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString();
        myTable = getDataSource();//stored in mem or retrieve from db again
        //linq or whatever you want to retrieve that row (if you need to go back to your datasource
        var name = from r in MyTable
              where r.ID == myId
              select r.Name;
    }
}
```

I would suggest adding whatever columns you need to dataKeyNames if that's possible.